# Servicestack autoquery custom convention doesn't work with PostgreSQL

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery, autoquery-servicestack

I have defined new implicit convention

```
autoQuery.ImplicitConventions.Add("%WithinLastDays", "{Field} > NOW() - INTERVAL '{Value} days'");
```

The problem is that for postgres connection the query is wrong translated into

```
WHERE "TABLE"."FIELD" > NOW() - INTERVAL ':0 days'
```

and it doesn't send parameter to database. In case of built in conventions it works fine.

**UPDATE**

I was trying to define EndsWithConvention but there is the same issue - parameter is not passed  to pgsql engine (however it is available in SqlExpression)

```
    autoQuery.EndsWithConventions
.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - {Value}", ValueFormat= "interval '{0} days ago'" });

    autoQuery.EndsWithConventions
.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval '{Value}'", ValueFormat= "{0} days ago" });
```

**UPDATE 2**
The below definition results in PostgresException: 42601: błąd składni w lub blisko "$1" (sorry for error in Polish)

```
autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval {Value}", ValueFormat= "{0} days ago" });
```

The generated query is

```
  SELECT here columns
        FROM table
        WHERE table."publication_date" >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval $1
        LIMIT 100
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - {Value}", ValueFormat= "interval {0} 'days ago'" });
```

generates

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...."publication_date" >=  CURRENT_DATE - $1
```

and issue PostgresException: 42883: operator doesn't exist: date - text

this is the dto definition

```
[Route("/search/tenders")]
    public class FindTenders : QueryDb<TenderSearchResult>
    {
        public int? PublicationDateWithinLastDays { get; set; }
    }
```

model:

```
public class EntitiySearchResult
{
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**
@mythz solved the registration problem and issue in using interval clause in my original query. The below definition works fine to get records within X days in the past from now. Thanks @mythz

```
  var autoQuery = new AutoQueryFeature() { MaxLimit = 100 };
            autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute
            {
                Template = "{Field} >= CURRENT_DATE + {Value}::interval",
                ValueFormat = "{0} days ago"
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{Value}` is replaced with a db parameter, if you want to change the value of the db parameter you [need to use ValueFormat](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#formatting-values), e.g. `ValueFormat="{0} days"`.

To define `ValueFormat` format an implicit convention you need to [register an EndsWithConventions](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#advanced-conventions), e.g:

```
autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute { 
    Template= "{Field} >= CURRENT_DATE + {Value}::interval", 
    ValueFormat= "{0} days ago" 
});
```

Also note you likely want `CURRENT_DATE + interval` not `-`.

Comment: I was trying to use EndsWithConvention and ValueFormat but still the parameter is not passed (I have checked the psql log with executed queries)

Comment: @marcinn It's a db param so the string doesn't need quoting, have you tried `Template = "... interval {Value}", ValueFormat = "{0} days ago"`?

Comment: I was also trying to define ValueFormat without quoting but this doesn't work - the statement is generated as `"DATE_FIELD" >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval ':0 day'`. The `:0` is not passed

Comment: @marcinn I don't get how, it should look like `interval :0` with the DB param like `2 days ago`. See my previous comment, there should not be any quotes in either your `Template` or `ValueFormat`.

Comment: I was trying to define this as `autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval {Value} days ago", ValueFormat= "{0} days ago" });` and it doesn't work  :-(

Comment: @marcinn please see my comment it's just `... interval {Value}` the days ago is only in the `ValueFormat`

Comment: sorry I had pasted it wrong to my comment. After correction I have PostgresException: 42601: syntax error  "$1 `autoQuery.EndsWithConventions.Add("WithinLastDays", new QueryDbFieldAttribute() { Template= "{Field} >=  CURRENT_DATE - interval {Value}", ValueFormat= "{0} days ago" });`

Comment: Please update your answer with exactly the code you're using.

Comment: @marcinn Also try moving `interval` to `ValueFormat` like `ValueFormat="interval '{0} days ago'"`

Comment: @marcinn it also needs casting, see my updated answer.